# git how to share code between two repository

Tags: git

I have two repository, repoA and repoB. repoA contains repoB and more some files and folders. Structure follows

```
repoA
--fileA
--fileB
--folderA
--folderB

repoB
--fileB 
--folderB
```

Both of the repository fileB and folderB common.

How can i achieve that if fileB and/or folderB modified in any repo then both will be updated.

If it is possible that is better, if not how can i merge repoB to repoA so that all commit to repoB present and also no changes made to other files which is not present in repoB. Most of the time repoB will be midified for common files and folders and repoA will be modified for those files and folders which are not present in repoB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Save the following script as "git-subfolder":

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter \
    "git ls-files -s | sed 's-\t-&$1/-' |
     GIT_INDEX_FILE=\$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
     git update-index --index-info &&
     mv \$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \$GIT_INDEX_FILE || true"  --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

**Note**: that script is not mine, I found it some time ago somewhere on the web, but no way to find it back to refer to it and give credit to its author...

Use it to move repoA and repoB into a subfolder, e.g. assuming you have clone repoA and repoB into cloneA and cloneB respectively:

```
cd cloneA
git-subfolder projectA
cd ../cloneB
git-subfolder projectB
```

Then merge them:

```
cd ../cloneA
git pull ../cloneB
```

You can then create a third subfolder, e.g. "common" and put fileB and folderB in there. Both "sub-projects" projectA and projectB must then refer to fileB and folderB in the common subfolder. You can also create symbolic links in both projectA and projectB to fileB and folderB.